# Reversing order of integration : Why no change in bounds in this example

Tags: integration, probability-theory

I could take this change of order of integration as it is, but when I try to understand why the bounds didn't change I really can't see why. Can anyone explain how we get this ? Thank you

$$\int_\Omega \int_0^\infty 1_{[0,X(\omega)}(x) dx dP(w) =  \int_0^\infty  \int_\Omega1_{[0,X(\omega)}(x)  dP(w) dx $$

$P$ is a probability measure.

$x=X(\omega)$, where $X$ is a random variable.

$\Omega$ the universe of events and $w$ an element of $\Omega$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are, $\Omega$ is an interval in $\omega$ independent of $x$. This commonly happens when you are integrating over a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then changing the order of integration does not affect the limits.

Comment: I agree for the rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But what is the general rule that gives us the right to reverse the order of integration when it's not (a rectangle in ) $\mathbb{R}^2$? for instance here $\Omega * [0, \infty ]$

Comment: @user30614 when the bounds are independent of each other; any sort of dependency in the inner integral may cause alteration of boundary conditions